# Typescript: Inference of "this" with higher order functions

Tags: typescript

When I define a function in an object literal, Typescript will correctly identify the type of `this`, e.g.:

```js
const test = {
  foo: function() {
    return { type: 'foo' }
  },
  bar: function() {
    // Usage of "this" is fine for Typescript.
    return { type: 'bar', foo: this.foo() }
  }
}
```

This breaks when I use a higher order function to wrap the function:

```js
// Some HOC passing through the "this" parameter.
function cacheValue<THIS, RESULT>(
  factory: (this: THIS) => RESULT
): (this: THIS) => RESULT {
  let instance: RESULT | undefined
  return function() {
    if (instance === undefined) {
      instance = factory.call(this)
    }
    return instance
  }
}

const testHOC = {
  foo: function() {
    return { type: 'foo' }
  },
  bar: cacheValue(function() {
    // error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
    return { type: 'bar', foo: this.foo() }
  })
}
```

Now Typescript incorrectly identifies the type of `this` in the function as `unknown`, so the call to `this.foo()` is an error: `error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Is there a way to get this to work

- without explicitly defining the type of `testHOC` (i.e. writing an interface), and
- without using an arrow function and referring to `testHOC` directly (because I might want to replace `testHoc.foo` later)?

Comment: this is not a first argument of the function when you put it into object. this is bind implicitly. So the whole inference by first property just fails hard. Also you really do not have first argument passed.

Comment: pls prove this statement: `Now Typescript *incorrectly* identifies the type of this in the function as void`, to me cachevalue `this` scope is `void` - thus `this.foo()` should throw

Comment: @MaciejSikora I don't understand. This is how you declare the type of `this` in Typescript. (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

Comment: @Estradiaz `this` is `void` for `cacheValue`, but not for the function it returns.

Comment: Why does `cacheValue`'s signature have its own `this` parameter?  It's a standalone function, not a method.  Shouldn't it be `function cacheValue<T, R>(factory: (this: T) => R): (this: T) => R;` instead?  This doesn't solve your inference problem, but it at least gets it to a place where it can be meaningfully discussed.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, of course, that was nonsense. But it does not solve the problem - please see the edited question.

Comment: I can't find any way to get contextual typing to work the way you want.  My only suggestion here is to refactor into `test.bar = cacheValue(test.bar)`.

Comment: i think it is valid to turn off typescript here -> `cacheValue(function(this:any){})`